# Filter Request Rows based on response time in nginx access log

Tags: nginx

172.31.0.19 - 106.208.175.228 - - [05/Jul/2020:17:40:44 +0000] "POST /api/v2/devices/ HTTP/1.1" 201 399 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"rt=25.299 uct="0.000" uht="25.300" urt="25.300"

This is the sample log from the access log. How I can print or separate the data based on rt 'request time' is higher than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Putting this data into a Time Series Database would be a first step I guess. You can try parsing the log files using the telegraf log parser and feeding the data into Questdb.io Then you can execute SQL queries against it based on time parameters, etc.

Comment: Any chance like this?  awk '$24>3000'  access.log  ? That was the last step to import the logfile on some log processing file then do all stuff. Actually My Nginx for 3-4 seconds takes more than 20sec for serving the request and then again processing under 2 sec